# Подставить значение переменной в echo

Tags: php

Формирую значение переменной из других переменных:

```
$peremennaya = "text".$peremennaya_1.$peremennaya_2."3";
```

Теперь нужно подставить значение сформированной переменной в echo, чтобы получить данные из массива имя которого равно сформированному значению.

Т.е. если переменная имеет значение "text123"
то нужно отобразить данные массива с именем $text123

```
 echo ($text123[1]);
```

Comment: налицо [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/191482) ..... лучше скажи что пытаешься решить, какая задача. Потому что ты явно делаешь какой-то жуткий костыль

Comment: Вывести массив с данными, чье имя == значению переменной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте "переменные переменных"

```
echo (${$peremennaya})
```

Вот ссылка на офф документацию на всякий случай http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Точно сформулировано!

Answer (score 0):

Удобнее будет хранить требуемые данные не в переменных, а в ассоциативном массиве, что бы иметь возможность получать данные по ключу.

```
$peremennaya = "text".$peremennaya_1.$peremennaya_2."3";
echo $data[$peremennaya];
```